# Page cache elimination in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, swap

Optimizing the page cache space for less memory utilization in some system where systems don't have swap space and external flash drive or hard disk. Is there any possibility that if we can remove or optimize the page cache size in kernel data structure?

Comment: Have you observed a particular instance where the page cache size is inefficient, that you could add into your question detail ?

Comment: kernel running on devices like routers, switches not having swap space and kernel running on small devices not having any flash drive or hard disk can be some example.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Tuning `vm.dirty_background_ratio` and `vm.dirty_ratio` will effectively reduce the page cache size.

More info at [Better Linux Disk Caching & Performance with vm.dirty_ratio & vm.dirty_background_ratio](https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/)

Comment: No; those cause the kernel to write *dirty* pages to disk more frequently, but not to remove clean ones from the cache.  You want vm.swappiness set to zero.

Comment: I have already tried this stuff but even after doing this and dropping the cache i.e. echo 3 >> /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches still in cache there remain around 180 MB is there any way to reduce the cache size further?